# How can I add paging to my store with loads data from the server via proxy?

Tags: javascript, extjs, pagination, extjs4.2

I'm using this store:

```
Ext.define('newStore', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'myModel',
  pageSize: 5,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/myJson.json',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'myThings',
      totalProperty: 'total'
    }
  }
});
```

And I'm using this pager:

```
  { 
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    store: 'newStore'
  }
```

The json:

```
{"total": 10, "success": true, "myThings": [{"thingNum": 1},{"thingNum": 2},{"thingNum": 3},{"thingNum": 4},{"thingNum": 5},{"thingNum": 6},{"thingNum": 7},{"thingNum": 8},{"thingNum": 9},{"thingNum": 10}]}
```

The problem is my store just loads all `myThings` into the grid even though my `pagingtoolbar` has 1-5 with total 10.

How can I get my grid to properly page?

Answer (score 0):

for this you should have your backend logic with pangination support, otherwiese you can use the memory proxy for local pagination as follows,

```
var localStore = Ext.define('localStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.store',
    model: 'myModel',
    proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    enablePaging: true
    },
    pageSize: 5
});
```

once your main store is loaded with the data, inside callback function populate that data into your memoryProxy store.

```
localStore.setProxy({
        data:records,
        type:'memory',
        enablePaging: true
    });

localStore.loadPage(1);
```

hope this helps you.